# Trying call useQuery after "if" in React app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

In my react app I receive gql after some function's work and I try to call apollo hook like this:

```
...
let data = {};
if(gqlQuery)
  data = useQuery(gqlQuery)
```

After it app falls down with

```
Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
useBaseQuery
src/react/hooks/utils/useBaseQuery.ts:21
  18 |             Promise.resolve().then(forceUpdate);
  19 |         }
  20 |         else {
> 21 |             forceUpdate();
     | ^  22 |         }
  23 |     }
  24 | });
```

What a problem and how to handle it?
p.s. I can't escape "if(gqlQuery)"

Comment: hooks rule broken, can't be called conditionally ... use skip option

Answer (score 0):

Try using this!

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(YOUR_QUERY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - useLazyQuery